# Scale-dependent displaying of a layer using OpenLayers plugin?

Tags: qgis, scale, qgis-openlayers-plugin, visibility

When I am creating a layer in QGIS the layer position/lines does not stay the same when I zoom in closer than, it seems like 1: 1000. I am adding 2 images to explain the problem. The moment I zoom in closer than 1: 1 000 then the original layer does not display correctly anymore.

Please, can you assist in this matter?

[image: Boundary1]
[image: Boundary2]

Comment: Are you using the **OpenLayers** plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using OpenLayers plugin

Comment: **OpenLayers** plugin has many issues. Try **Quick Map Services** plugin instead, it generally gives better results.

Comment: Thank you I loaded QuickMapServices, but can't find anything similar to the Google Satellite background I need. The Landsat (GIS Lab-info) option failed to download. I tried the other options, but the background I need. I am looking for something similar to Google Earth as a background. Is there another option in QuickMap I dont see?

Comment: It does solve my initial scale problem thank you. I loaded the OSM standard background and it does work. Another option that does not want to download is the MApQuest_Arial option. This might be similar to google earth/satellite

Comment: Okay now I can not see the QMS option at all in QGIS?! I've installed the plugin, but it is nowhere to be found?! Restarted QGIS but no success?! I;ve read from other conversations in this blog that I need to go to the Settings in QMS and activate the Contributed Services, but first have to get to the QMS downloaded plugin before I can do that>?! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I was away. Please, see if my answer helps you.

Comment: I figured it out! Ignore above comments and questions :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OpenLayers** plugin has many issues. Instead, try the **Quick Map Services** plugin because it generally gives better results.

You may download it from the **Plugins** repository:

[image]

Then, you will find it under the **Web** Menu:

[image]

or directly on the QGIS Main Page:

[image]

If the default services are not enough for you, you may unlock many other services from `Web` > `QuickMapServices` > `Settings` > `More Services`:

[image]

Once you have done this, you will have access to many services like, for example, **Google Satellite**:

[image]

and you will obtain the desired result:

[image]