# Getting watermarks on my satellite image

Tags: qgis

[image]I am Using QGIS 2.16.1. When I open the Google satellite image by using open layers plugin I am getting watermarks on it. So many time I uninstalled and installed. Even I installed new version of QGIS. I went through the same question replied by you. 
[How to close watermarks window in QGIS Openlayers plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24646/how-to-close-watermarks-window-in-qgis-openlayers-pluginbut)

but the link you suggested has been removed already.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @DeepaEswarapu. If you use the **QuickMapServices** plugin instead, you can use **Bing Satellite** which I don't think contains any watermarks (or atleast I couldn't see any!). You can download the plugin from `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`. Once installed, go to `Web > QuickMapServices > Settings > More services > Get contributed pack` to make sure you get all the latest services.

Answer (score 2):

You may try using the **Quick Map Services** plugin, it shouldn't include any watermark. See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232978/scale-dependent-displaying-of-a-layer-using-openlayers-plugin/233290#233290) for a help on how to install it.

Using the `Google Satellite` Service, it seems that you will still have watermarks on the map (but not on the bottom-right of the image you attached in the original question):

[image]

An alternative would be the `Mapbox Satellite` Service from the `Mapbox` Menu:

[image]

which seems not showing any watermark.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I installed QUICK MAP SERVICES. but the same problem.

Comment: Could you please share the location of the image you attached in the question and which service are your trying to use?

Comment: satellite image located in doha, qatar. we are getting satellite imagery from our supplier. by using that satellite imagery i need to get high quality print outs (A1 and A0) and soft copy  for our clients . so I tried to get Jpeg formate from the QGIS software. but i am getting these issues.

Comment: @DeepaEswarapu please, see my edited answer. If you want high quality prints, I wouldn't suggest the jpeg format since it is a compression format (maybe .png or .tiff are better).

Comment: thanks a lot for your response again. i saved image by using Mapbox Satellite, and i am not getting any watermarks. but i am missing the details from the construction location. actually we need satellite image for those details. i am adding my image in edited answer

Comment: @DeepaEswarapu try to switch to other services, you may try what you are looking for. Therefore,  I see that you tried to edit my answer: instead, edit your question for adding any explanation you think useful. I'm quite sure that Google Satellite service has the most accurate and updated results, but you need to find a compromise because the best solution would be possible only if you have a private satellite :)

Answer (score 1):

A alternative to the OpenLayers plugin is TileLayerPlugin.
Maybe this error does not occur with this plugin:

Here are the docs:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin)