# Google Satellite imagery gone wild with QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, imagery, google, satellite

I'm using the OpenLayers plugin (version 1.4.3) for my satellite imagery.  When I'm at 1:565 or less (the number on the right is bigger) everything is fine.  See image below.
[image]

When I'm at 1:564 or greater the satellite image is incorrectly aligned / scaled.  In this case, I change the number is the bottom readout (circled in red) to avoid moving the map in any way.
[image]

I am using an API key.  And can zoom into 1:282 before the image goes away (what appears to be the plugin's way of letting you know the imagery isn't supported at that scale.

I haven't noticed this behavior with Bing imagery, or Google Hybrid, but can't zoom in as far either either case.

Comment: This is a known bug of the OpenLayers plugin. Try the QuickMapServices plugin instead. With the "Contributed pack", it has Google imagery too.

Comment: See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232978/scale-dependent-displaying-of-a-layer-using-openlayers-plugin/233290#233290)

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ if you add it as an answer I'll accept it.